# Let $R$ be an equivalence relation on $A$...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

knowing that in $A$ is more than three elements. we define $R^c=A\times A \setminus R$, then which of these statements is surely correct?
a) if $R^c$ is transitive, then $R$ has only one equivalence class. 
b) if $R^c$ is symmetric, then $R$ has only one equivalence class. 
c) if $R^c$ is irreflexive, then $R$ has only one equivalence class.
d) if $R^c$ is transitive, then $R$ is the identity relation. 
e) if $R^c$ is symmetric, then $R$ is the universal relation (full relation $R=A\times A$). 

I am really trying to find the purpose or what should I understand to solve this question, I might be able to track this question while writing an example set $A$ and writing a relation with $16$ elements and start trying to disprove each one of the options, but that really made me just complicate myself a little and saw that there was a high chance I'll make lots of mistakes missing elements etc.. I was wondering, there must be some better way to solve this question, since if the question asked for $10$ elements, my approach won't work and I will hesitate to check with less elements than $10$. 
I can't understand the idea of one equivalence class, I understand the definition of equivalence class, but seems like not deep enough. 
I would really appreciate to see approaches from more experienced people in this question and how would you solve it, I appreciate all the help, thanks in advance. 
Final answer is (a).

Comment: Think of equivalence classes as partitioning a set.  An ordered pair is in $R^c$ if and only if its components are in two different members of the partition.

Comment: @RobertShore thanks for the comment, I still don't get the overal idea, I know that if $R$ has only one equivalence class, then all it's elements are taken from the cross product of the equivalence class by itself, so I could say $R^c$ would be empty by then, but that still doesn't help me decide which answer is correct. I didn't understand the idea of a pair in $R^c$ iff its components are in two different members of the partition, I would really appreciate an explanation thanks alot though

Comment: Since $R$ having one equivalence class is equivalent to $R^c =\emptyset$, you can translate the first three to a) $R^c$ is transitive $\implies$ $R^c = \emptyset$, b) $R^c$ is symmetric $\implies$ $R^c = \emptyset$, c) $R^c$ is irreflexive $\implies$ $R^c = \emptyset$. It might be helpful to translate the various statements about $R^c$ into statements about $R$. For example, "$R^c$ is transitive" means that for $a,b,c \in A, a\not Rb$ and $b\not Rc \implies a\not Rc$.

Comment: Draw a picture (literally) of $A$, and then arbitrarily partition $A$ into a bunch of compartments.  Two elements of $A$ are equivalent if and only if they're in the same compartment, which means that two elements of $A$ are not equivalent if and only if they're in different compartments.  Use your picture to consider your questions.  For example, you'll see that $R^c$ is **always** symmetric and irreflexive.  The idea of one equivalence class is simply that every two elements of $A$ are equivalent to each other.  In terms of the picture , it means that all of $A$ is a single compartment.